# How to cache Windows docker images on Linux?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-for-windows, windows-container, container-image

What is the best way to cache Windows container images on a Linux system? 
Setting up a registry mirror won't work because pulling a Windows image from Linux gets me a

`no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries`

One option would be setting up the registry mirror in a Windows inside a Virtual Machine, but I hope there are better solutions.

Comment: I think setting up a registry is still the best option. Run the registry on your linux host, and  perform the pull/push operation from your Windows host.

Comment: @larsks Ah, I see. Will try it out. Didn't know the docker client is causing the error (and not the service).

Comment: To be fair, I haven't tested that idea, but I believe it's entirely a client issue. Let me know how it works out.

Comment: @larsks You were right. It is a client issue. I managed to create a registry mirror on Linux and configure the Windows docker daemon to use it. According to this: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/ it is currently not possible to configure a pass-through-cache though. But no big problem for me. If you transform your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image architecture that Docker attempts to pull is determined by the client, not by the server. You can run your registry server under Linux and perform you `docker push/pull` from Windows.